# I am creating an Wikipedia search engine but problem is that program turns off after giving output, please check description

Tags: python

```py
import wikipedia

result = wikipedia.summary(input(), sentences = 12)
print(result)
```

I am creating an project and as an beginner I really don't know how to code, But this code is not enough it just asks for input for only one time and program turns off so can anyone tell me, **The problem is that, what code should I add to make it ask again for input after giving output (Its like an Wikipedia search engine)**

Comment: You could use a ```while``` loop

Comment: *"i really don't know how to code"* Then you should learn it. There are countless resources on the Internet to learn Python and frankly speaking, Stack Overflow can not replace learning a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope so this resolves your problem
**We are simply using a very basic `while` loop here. The basic idea is that it will ask the user their query after that it will ask them to search again or not if yes it will repeat again else it will close.**

```py
import wikipedia

while True:
    query = input("What would you like to search for: ").lower()
    result = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 12)
    print(result, "\n")
    continue_ = input("Would you like to search again[y]/n: ").lower()
    if (continue_ == "") or (continue_ == "y"):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Any more queries or doubts on this answer are readily welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a while loop.

```
import Wikipedia

while True:
    result = wikipedia.summary(input(), sentences = 12)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Nice attempt, but try putting some examples and some snippets from the user's code, and to top it all off add an explanation to make the user understand and implement on their own. Its just a tip for you please don't take it in a negative way.

Comment: Hello @DoctorJJJulius, it's great that you put your answer with some code examples, your answer is good actually, I suggest adding up a few more details into it cause there might be some people who might downvote your question & causing you not to ask anymore, Thank you!